# Compiling NumPy and uploading to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, numpy, aws-lambda

I followed https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html guide by AWS until the virtual env part.

My zip file structure looks like this -

```
bin
numpy
numpy-1.15.2.dist-info
myscript.py
```

I get an error when I upload the zip file to AWS Lambda. The error says -

```
{
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'testingUpload'"
}
```

All my script file contains is

```
import numpy

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print ("This is the test package")
```

When I upload the zip file without `import numpy`, it works fine.

```
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print ("This is the test package")
```

Comment: 'I get an error'.  Is that all you tell us?  Be prepared for some scolding and down votes.

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry, I have updated my question. It is a generic error, so that is why I didn't include it.